# WSDL multiple endpoints

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

If my server has a single endpoint:

```
Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:6789/webservice/library", new LibraryImpl());
```

The client can connect to it through

```
LibraryImplService service = new LibraryImplService();
LibraryInterface library = service.getLibraryImplPort();
```

If I have multiple endpoints:

```
Endpoint endpoint1 = Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:6789/webservice/library", new LibraryImpl());
Endpoint endpoint2 = Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:6799/webservice/library", new LibraryImpl());
Endpoint endpoint3 = Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:6809/webservice/library", new LibraryImpl());
```

How can I get my client connect to the proper URL? 
Instead of

```
LibraryInterface library = service.getLibraryImplPort();
```

Could I simply use the known port number? For instance if I want to connect to the URL published by `endpoint1`, would this work?

```
LibraryInterface library = 6789;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the entire address string that your client will be connecting to. JAX-WS doesn't provide a method that'll alter only the port. What you'll then have is

```
BindingProvider bndProvider = (BindingProvider)library;
bndProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://localhost:6789/webservice/library");
```